# Having trouble understanding the tabular environment

Tags: tables, multicolumn

Here's my code. I'm trying to generate a five column table with column headings, and a title. Columns centered, with the table completely "lined" by vertical lines only.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[]{amsfonts}
\usepackage[]{enumerate}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amstext}
...
\begin{document}  
...
\begin{tabluar}{C|C|C|C|C} % Line 167
    \hline 
    \multicolumn{5}{C}{\text{Dwayne Johnson}} \\
    \hline 
    \text{Dogs} &\text{Cats} & \text{snek} & \text{fish} & \text{Cube} \\ % Line 171
    \hline
    0.8234578283 & 0.4387443597 & 0.4897643958 & 0.2760250770 & 0.4983640520 \\ % Line 173
    0.6948286230 & 0.3815584571 & 0.4455862007 & 0.6797026769 & 0.9597439585 \\ 
    0.3170994801 & 0.7655167881 & 0.6463130101 & 0.6550980040 & 0.3403857267 \\ 
    0.9502220488 & 0.7951999011 & 0.7093648309 & 0.1626117352 & 0.5852677510 \\ 
    0.0344460805 & 0.1868726046 & 0.7546866820 & 0.1189976816 & 0.2238119395 \\
    \hline 
\end{tabular}   % Line 179
...
\end{document}
```

It's not compiling, and I'm receiving a gamut of errors:

> (1) Latex Error: Environment tabular undefined.
>   (2) Misplaced \omit.
>   Underfull \hbox (Badness 10000) at paragraphs line 171 -- 172.
>   (3) Misplaced \noalign.
>   (4) Misplaced alignment tab character &.
>   Underfull \hbox (Badness 10000) at paragraphs line 173 -- 178.
>   (*) A few more error (4)'s.
>   (8) Another \noalign
>   (9) Misplaced \crcr. Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. Extra }, or forgotten $. Latex Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{tabular}. Missing $ inserted. Line 179

My code is actually printing the capital C's instead of taking them as a parameter. But it was doing that without the newcolumn macro so I know that's not the issue. Thank you.

Comment: Misspelled *tabular*. Sorry for wasting everyone's time. But I'm new to LaTex so if you got any tips on mine that would be cool, thank you.

Comment: A matter of taste, but I suggest to have a look at https://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/markusp/teaching/guides/guide-tables.pdf

Comment: @samcarter And in the same vein, but reduced to the essential (and phrased more authoritatively), the ‹booktabs› vignette.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have already noted, you have misspelled `tabular`. In addition, the column specifiers are mentioned as `C` rather than `c`. Correcting both, your code compiles fine to yield the table shown.

Is it what you are expecting?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

*Tabular* is spelled *tabular*, not *tabluar*.